# How to save values in Vector using R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I am supposed to find the mean and standard deviation at each given sample size (N), using the "FOR LOOP". I started writing the code as below, I am required to save all the means into vector "p". How do I save all the means into one vector?

```
sample.sizes =c(3,10,50,100,500,1000)
mean.sds = numeric(0)
for ( N in sample.sizes ){
    x <- rnorm(3,mean=0,sd=1)
    mean.sds[i]
}
mean(x)
```

Comment: (1) What is `mean.sds[i]` supposed to do? First, the variable is length 0, so `[i]` will always be `NULL`. Second, do you mean to assign to it? (2) Your loop overwrites `x` each time, so your post-`for` expression `mean(x)` is going to calculate the average of the last iteration of the loop. (3) Finally, what exactly are you trying to get in the end, a vector of averages?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are doing many thing wrong?

- If you are using variable `N` in for loop, you are not using it anywhere
- `for (N in 'some_vector')` actually means N will take that value one by one.  So `N` in sample sizes will first take, 3 then 10 then 50 and so on.
- Now where does `i` come into picture?
- You are calculating `x` for each iteration of `N`.  In fact you are not using `N` anywhere in the loop?
- first `x` will return 3 values.  In the next line you intend to store these three values in just `i`th value of mean.sds where `i` is unknown and storing three values into one value, as it is, is not logically possible.

Do you want this?

```
sample.sizes =c(3,10,50,100,500,1000)
mean.sds = numeric(0)
for ( i in seq_along(sample.sizes )){
  x <- rnorm(sample.sizes[i], mean=0, sd=1)
  mean.sds[i] <- mean(x)
}
mean.sds

[1]  0.6085489531 -0.1547286299  0.0052106559 -0.0452804986 -0.0374094936  0.0005667246
```

- I replaced `N` with `seq_along(sample.sizes)` which will give iterations equal to the number of that vector.  Six in this example.
- I passed each `i`th element to first argument of `rnorm` to generate these many random values.
- Stored each random value into single vector.  calculated its mean (one value only) and stored in ith value of your empty vector.